# Как модернизировать данный код php?

Tags: php

```
<div class="apartaments-floor active">
          <span>Выберите этаж:</span>
            <?php $loopCounter = 0 ;  ?>
            <?php $etageNumber = 1 ;?>
            <?php while ( have_rows('river') ) : the_row(); ?>


              <?php  if( get_row_layout() == 'etage' ): ?>
                <?php 


                  ?>
                  <?php if($loopCounter % 10 == 0): ?>
                    <div class="apartaments-row">
                      <span><?php echo $etageNumber?>-<?php echo $loopCounter + 10?></span>
                      <ul>
                  <?php endif;   $loopCounter++;?>
                  <li><span><?php echo $etageNumber; $etageNumber++?></span></li>

                <?php if($loopCounter % 10 == 0): ?>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                <?php endif; ?>



              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div>
```

Суть в том что каждые 10 пунктов создают новую структуру ul куда выводится все пункты. И все отлично работает , но у меня не ровное количество пунктов. Т.е их постоянно 61 пункт. Как сделать что бы последний пункт , он же и 61 не создавал новую UL а становился последним , 11 пунктом в 6 рядом?

Comment: Вам нужно посчитать количество итераций (сохраняя в переменную) до начала цикла и в конце добавить условие которое будет проверять если $loopCounter равен новой переменной(количество итераций) и не равен кратному 10 (if($loopCounter % 10 != 0)), не создавать новый ул, а добавить li в существующий

Comment: *Т.е их постоянно 61 пункт* - считайте циклы и на последнем if($loop != 6 and $loopCounter % 10 == 0): ?> обрабатывать до конца